# Anchor tag/links inside textarea htmltext

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am trying to display the following inside a textrea as HTML text. Text is coming up fine, but the anchor tag is not working.

```
<p>
   <font color="#5680e0">
        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
             <strong>Google Website</strong>
        </a>
   </font>
</p>
```

My flex code where text area is defined is as

```
<mx:TextArea id="leftArticle" selectable="false" borderVisible="false" top="136" verticalScrollPolicy="off" fontFamily="Arial" color="#333333" condenseWhite="false" focusEnabled="false" focusAlpha="0" editable="true" fontSize="12" width="245" height="285"/>
```

code where htmlText is assigned

```
leftArticle.htmlText = htmldata;
```

Any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: Did you ensure the text area has HTML enabled?

Comment: @JuanT yes the font color is changed, but its not clickable like anchor tag

Comment: If Xavier didn't answer your question, could you post the code your using to create this text area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. Adding the following to the textarea code the links are now working properly.

```
textarea.mx_internal::getTextField().enabled=true;
```

Comment: Bear in mind this property is subject to change should you update the version of flex you are compiling against ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the anchor anywhere in your HTML. Where is the  tag which define it?
I don't understand why you try to display HTML as text in a p tag but I will assume you know what you are doing.

You need 2 things to properly use an anchor:

1. an id tag in your HTML
2. the right link to call it (with # marker)

To follow your example, your HTML would looks like this:

```
 <p id="sample">
  <font color="#5680e0">
   <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
    <strong>Google Website</strong>
   </a>
  </font>
 </p>
```

And your link that calls the page where this text is displayed with the marker to position the page exactly where it is:

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/yourpage.html#sample">Check out the sample code!</a>
```

Try to be more specific next time you ask a question please. And indent your code :)

Comment: Sharmacal, can you confirm that you are actually trying to use an "anchor" tag? As in, going to a page and scrolling to the appropriate ID? I think that was just a mis-used term and what you really want to accomplish is just a hyperlink that links somewhere else. If you do want to just anchor, Xavier has the correct answer here.

Comment: @JuanT I am using html <a> tag that is used to link to somewhere else , not within the page.

Answer (score 0):

Set the selectable property to true.

http://www.rockabit.com/2008/10/27/executing-html-links-in-flex/

Comment: made the changes but still not working... even the hand cursor do not come for the links.

Comment: i have got the solution. Need not make selectable true. textarea.mx_internal::getTextField().enabled=true; Thanks.